Proving that $f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{\sin x}x&\text{if }x>0\\1&\text{if }x=0\end{cases}$ is not in $L^1([0,\infty))$
We consider the function $f\colon [0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ defined as
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{\sin x}{x} & \text{if $x > 0$}\\
1 &\text{if $x=0$}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
I must prove that $|f|\notin L^1([0,\infty))$. I reasoned as follows, but I'm not sure if it's all formally correct, especially the first inequality.
\begin{align}
\int_{[0,+\infty)}\left|\frac{\sin x}{x} \right|\;d\lambda&\ge  \int_{[\pi,\infty)}\left |\frac{\sin x}{x}\right|\;d\lambda\\
&=\int_{\bigsqcup_{h=1}^\infty[h\pi,(h+1)\pi)}\left |\frac{\sin x}{x} \right|\;d\lambda \\
&=\sum_{h=1}^\infty \int_{[h\pi, (h+1)\pi)}\left|\frac{\sin x}{x} \right|\;d\lambda\\
&= \sum_{h=1}^\infty \int_{[h\pi, (h+1)\pi]}\left|\frac{\sin x}{x} \right|\;d\lambda\\
&=\sum_{h=1}^\infty\int_{h\pi}^{(h+1)\pi}\left | \frac{\sin x}{x}\right|\;dx\\
&\color{green}{\ge} \sum_{h=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(h+1)\pi}\int_{h\pi}^{(h+1)\pi}|\sin x|\; dx\\
&= \sum_{h=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(h+1)\pi}\int_0^\pi |\sin t|\; dt\\
&=\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{h=1}^\infty \frac{1}{h+1}=\infty
\end{align}
Where the green inequality $$\color{green}{\left |\frac{\sin x}{x}\right|\ge \frac{1}{(h+1)\pi} |\sin x| \; \forall x\in [h\pi, (h+1)\pi]}$$

Skip the line with $\int_0^\infty  {\left| {\sin t} \right|dt}$. That integral does not exist.

@Gary, sorry I have now corrected it.

Looks fine to me. Another way is to note that $|\frac{\sin x}{x}|\geq\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x}=\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2x}=\frac{1}{2x}-\frac{\cos(2x)}{2x}$. By Dirichlet's test, $\int\limits_1^{\infty}\frac{\cos(2x)}{2x}dx$ converges, and so it will not be able to cancel the divergent integral of $\frac{1}{2x}$.
